# error: No module named pillow, requests or pywhatkit

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, importerror

pywhatkit, requests, and pillow are already installed in my system. But, during importing any one of these, ImportError occurs.

[image]

After installing it through jupyter notebook, I still got the same error.

[image]
[image]

Actually I am a student and a noob in this field, so you can underestimate me. and feel free to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using python 2 instead of python 3. This particular error happens to me too. I think it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Installing via pip on your local won’t necessarily install it for the kernel in your jupyter notebook. I typically write something like `%pip install {libraries_here}` into a cell. After running that cell, I restart the kernel and the packages should be there.

Comment: Still not working. Still I got the same ImportError.

Comment: Can you post the outputs you received when you ran the commands?

Comment: Make sure you use `%` instead of `!` in front of `pip install pillow`. There’s a difference between those two detailed here - https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/. The blog post is quite old but it should explain what’s going on and the `%` magic commands are now baked into jupyter - so there should be no setup to use them.